# Mocking an API function gives error while testing the code

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Below is my App.js code for your reference

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const fetchTheComments = async () => {
    let commentsFetched = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1`
    );
    return commentsFetched;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing Jest-Enzyme</h1>
      <button
        id="fetch-comments"
        onClick={() => {
          fetchTheComments();
        }}
      >
        Fetch
      </button>
      <p>
        {JSON.stringify(fetchTheComments())
          ? JSON.stringify(fetchTheComments())
          : ""}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is my App.test.js code for your reference

```
import App from "./App";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import mockAxiosApi from "../src/__mocks__/mockAxiosApi";

describe("Before testing", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
  });
  test("render the correct title", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toBe("Testing Jest-Enzyme");
  });
  test("button click", () => {
    wrapper.find("#fetch-comments").simulate("click");
    expect(wrapper.find("comments")).not.toBe("");
  });
  test("should fetch comments", async () => {
    wrapper.find("#fetch-comments").simulate("click");
    mockAxiosApi.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: {},
      })
    );
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    let response = await wrapper.instance().fetchTheComments();
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

[image: Getting the below error while doing npm run test]

I am not sure why i am getting the error, i have one lambda function inside the component which i am testing but whenever i run a test getting an error stating fetchTheComments function is null. I have pasted my App.js and App.test.js here for your reference. Can someone help me in this issue ?

Comment: There's no 'instance' in functional comments. This makes Enzyme less effective for them.

Comment: @EstusFlask, thanks for your time, please let me know if you have any alternatives for the above approach

Comment: React Testing Library is common. It has waitFor to be not strictly tied to a function that works asynchronously because it's inaccessible outside functional component.

Comment: Even i tried like this also test("should fetch comments", async () => {
    wrapper.find("#fetch-comments").simulate("click");
    mockAxiosApi.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: {},
      })
    );
    let mockApi = jest.fn();
    await waitFor(() => expect(mockApi).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });

Comment: Then also i am facing an error like expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

Comment: Why do you expect mockApi to be called? It's local variable that you've defined 1 line above and didn't use anywhere. Check how React Testing Library works, You assert effects that api request causes on rendered component, not a request itself. You physically cannot access fetchTheComments outside functional component.

Comment: ok @EstusFlask let me check thanks